# Python pandas: Calculated Week number overlaps with two months

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that contains daily data of the last five years. Beside values column, data frame also contains date field and regulatory year columns. I wanted to create two columns: the regulatory week number and the regulatory month number. The regulatory year starts from the 1st of April and ends on 31st March. So I used the following code to generate regulatory week number and month number:

```
df['Week'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week > 13, df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week-13,df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week + 39)

df['month'] =df['date'].dt.month
months = ['Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar']
df['month'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['month'], ordered=True, categories=months)
df['month number'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: months.index(x)+1)
```

After creating the above-mentioned two columns, my data frame looks like as follow:

```
 RY   month  Week   Value 1  Value 2         Value 3            Value 4      month number
   2016   Apr     1   0.00000  0.00000          0.000000           0.00000            1
   2016   Apr     2   1.31394  0.02961          1.313940           0.02961            1
   2016   Apr     3   4.98354  0.07146          4.983540           0.07146            1
   2016   Apr     4   4.30606  0.05742          4.306060           0.05742            1
   2016   Apr     5   1.94634  0.01958          1.946340           0.01958            1
   2016   May     5   0.25342  0.01625          0.253420           0.01625            2
   2016   May     6   0.64051  0.00777          0.640510           0.00777            2
   2016   May     7   1.26451  0.02994          1.264510           0.02994            2
   2016   May     8   2.71035  0.08150          2.194947           0.08150            2
   2016   May     9  11.95120  0.13386          1.624328           0.13386            2
   2016   Jun    10   6.93051  0.08126          6.930510           0.08126            3
   2016   Jun    11   1.18872  0.03953          1.188720           0.03953            3
   2016   Jun    12   3.19961  0.05760          0.924562           0.05760            3
   2016   Jun    13   3.90429  0.04985          0.956445           0.04985            3
   2016   Jun    14   0.84002  0.01738          0.840020           0.01738            3
   2016   Jul    14   0.07358  0.00562          0.073580           0.00562            4
   2016   Jul    15   0.78253  0.03014          0.782530           0.03014            4
   2016   Jul    16   1.23036  0.01816          1.230360           0.01816            4
   2016   Jul    17   0.62948  0.01341          0.629480           0.01341            4
   2016   Jul    18   0.45513  0.00552          0.455130           0.00552            4
```

Now I want to create a data frame that contains mean of  values column based on Week. So I used following command to calculate the mean:

```
mean_df = df.groupby('Week')['Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4'].mean().reset_index()
```

The new dataframe looks like as follow:

```
Week   Value 1   Value 2          Value 3           Value 4
  1   3.013490  0.039740          1.348016          0.039740
  2   3.094456  0.045142          3.094456          0.045142
  3   1.615948  0.027216          1.615948          0.027216
  4   2.889245  0.043998          1.903319          0.043998
  5   0.431549  0.009679          0.431549          0.009679
  6   1.045670  0.017302          1.045670          0.017302
  7   2.444196  0.034304          2.444196          0.034304
  8   1.041210  0.026464          0.938129          0.026464
  9   2.068607  0.030550          0.921176          0.030550
 10   2.400118  0.051476          2.400118          0.051476
 11   1.738332  0.035362          1.738332          0.035362
 12   1.369790  0.038576          0.914780          0.038576
 13   1.921781  0.021218          0.749460          0.021218
 14   1.471432  0.027367          1.471432          0.027367
 15   2.722526  0.053794          1.676559          0.053794
 16   3.132406  0.043520          1.195321          0.043520
 17   0.733952  0.021142          0.733952          0.021142
 18   0.645236  0.014454          0.645236          0.014454
 19   2.466326  0.049704          0.879481          0.049704
 20   2.111326  0.013262          0.682253          0.013262
 21   1.301004  0.023048          1.301004          0.023048
 22   0.705360  0.023439          0.705360          0.023439
 23   1.323438  0.019103          1.323438          0.019103
 24   0.569906  0.012540          0.569906          0.012540
 25   7.898792  0.034246          1.382349          0.034246
 26   0.896413  0.013013          0.896413          0.013013
 27   4.478349  0.039749          1.703887          0.039749
 28   5.807160  0.052526          2.036502          0.052526
 29   3.308176  0.043984          2.117939          0.043984
 30   1.991078  0.046058          1.991078          0.046058
 31   0.806589  0.016945          0.806589          0.016945
 32   2.091860  0.029234          2.091860          0.029234
 33   1.149280  0.025194          1.149280          0.025194
 34   4.746376  0.067742          2.863484          0.067742
 35   5.128558  0.029608          1.537541          0.029608
 36   2.765563  0.052125          2.765563          0.052125
 37   2.314376  0.036046          2.314376          0.036046
 38   2.552290  0.030626          1.483397          0.030626
 39   1.456778  0.037448          1.456778          0.037448
 40   1.212090  0.024698          1.212090          0.024698
 41   4.729104  0.037646          1.296358          0.037646
 42   3.412830  0.053132          3.412830          0.053132
 43   8.916526  0.050044          1.839411          0.050044
 44   2.450281  0.029806          0.942205          0.029806
 45   2.156186  0.024064          2.156186          0.024064
 46   2.336330  0.042538          2.336330          0.042538
 47   1.798326  0.025270          1.798326          0.025270
 48   1.352004  0.018382          1.352004          0.018382
 49  10.220510  0.073480          1.607830          0.073480
 50   2.575344  0.047760          2.575344          0.047760
 51   1.226056  0.028676          1.226056          0.028676
 52   0.470392  0.009991          0.466561          0.009991
```

Now I want to insert the month and month name from the above data frame to the new data frame. I thought to merge the two data frames together based on 'Week' but I found that the same week number is assigned to the two different months (in the first data frame). For example, Week 5 is assigned to April and May.

Ideally, a week number is assigned to only one month. I am not sure whether I am calculating the week number in the right manner or not. Has anyone come across the same problem? Any advice on how to calculate the week number so that a week number does not overlap with two months.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, week 5 contains some days in April and some in May. So it's not possible to assign week 5 (as a whole) to a single month.

Perhaps you could assign the month in which the first day of the week falls?